# How to write comments in Kibana console?

Tags: console, comments, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

Can you provide me with a hint how to comment out lines in [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) Dev Tools console? I am interested in comment syntax.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Kibana dev tools **does not support the comment within the query**.

However, you can use `#` before or after the query or in-between queries to write a comment.

```
# This is a  comment
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

# This is another comment
POST /index/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "abra ka dabra"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can comment out one line at a time by using `#`. For instance:

```
# This is a search command
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were to comment out a line or lines, you could add `/* */`, for example, `/* "field": "statType.keyword" */`

```
GET /exercise-index/_search
{ 
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["content"]
  }, 
  "query": {
    "exists": {"field": "inclination"}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "location": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "location"
        /* "size": 10 */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

at the query above, we commented out a line in agg with `/* */`.

PS:

1. The syntax check will fail after you add `/* */` on a line, but it does not affect the query.
2. After add `/* */`, you need to remove comma at the line before to meet the json syntax.

Comment: This didn't work for me (version 6.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 8.6 definitely supports `//` (double slash) as a way of commenting a line and leaving a text comment right inside a query:

```
GET edge-rsas-access-prod/_search?size=0    
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "lt": "now-1d/d" // setting a timeframe
      }
    }
  }
}
```